# Creating an interface with generic methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to define an interface with a generic method, that is implemented for specific types in classes that implement the interface. Is it possible to do something *like* this:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface {
    T MyMethod<T>(); 
}

public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface {
    int MyMethod<int>() {return 1;} 
    double MyMethod<float> {return 1.0;}
    T MyMethod<T> {throw new NotImplementedException();}
}
```

And then in the client code:

```cs
MyImplementation a = new(); 
int i = a.MyMethod<int>(); 
double d = a.MyMethod<double>();
string s = a.MyMethod<string>(); // throws NotImplementedException
```

EDIT:

People mentioned - rightly so - what problem I'm trying to solve here.

The problem is I have a class that is a factory for several slightly different classes. I could implement it like so:

```cs
public interface IMyFactory {
    int CreateInt(); 
    double CreateDouble(); 
}
```

Or, even more specific to my use-case:

```cs
public interface IModellingService{
    AddPointCmd GetAddPointCmd(); 
    AddLineCmd GetAddLineCmd();
    // ... and so on ... 
}
```

The works, but it just becomes so verbose. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @DenisMicheal no, it is not, at least in the form requested.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You have a problem X and assume the solution would be Y (C++ template specialization). This doesn't exist in C# so you ask about specialization, not the actual problem X. What's the *actual* problem? You may be able to solve it using different techniques, eg extension methods or type constraints. Extension methods would provide better type safety than this code because `.MyMethod<string>` wouldn't even compile

Comment: There are other options too, depending on the actual problem. If the accepted types implement a common interface with the members needed by `MyMethod`,  you can use it as a type constraint, removing the need for specializations. C# 11 (.NET 7) added generic static abstract methods in interfaces which means operators can be part of generic interfaces as well, making it easier to define type constraints

Comment: Why don't you have three different `MyImplementation` classes then?

Answer (score 0):

From pure technical standpoint of view (without getting into "whys"):  you can't provide "specific overrides" for generic methods, but you can analyze requested type and provide specific implementation for the case:

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface 
{
    public T MyMethod<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            return (T)(object)1; // get int
        
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
            return (T)(object)1.0; // get double

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But IMO you should heavily consider if such generic method is "generic enough" and should be actually generic (but without seeing actual use-case it is hard to tell what would be appropriate design here).

Comment: Extension methods would offer better type safety. This is an XY problem and we don't know the X.